# How to distinguish between human and animal bones in Wikidata?

Tags: wikidata

The two topics

- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q16343  (Clavicle)
- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q835986 (Baculum, Penis bone)

are both instances of Q265868 (Bone). However, the clavicle is a human (and animal) bone, whereas the Baculum is afaik not a human bone.

How can I distinguish human bones from non-human bones? Is there a Wikidata property for this?

Comment: AFAIK, FMO is about human anatomy only, so perhaps something like this: https://w.wiki/3yx Check also other identifiers.